# AngularJS: structuring a web application with multiple ng-apps

Tags: design, web-applications, angularjs

The blogosphere has a number of articles on the topic of AngularJS app structuring guidelines such as these (and others):

- http://www.johnpapa.net/angular-app-structuring-guidelines/
- http://codingsmackdown.tv/blog/2013/04/19/angularjs-modules-for-great-justice/
- http://danorlando.com/angularjs-architecture-understanding-modules/
- http://henriquat.re/modularizing-angularjs/modularizing-angular-applications/modularizing-angular-applications.html

However, one scenario I have yet to come across for guidelines and best practices is the case where you have a large web application containing multiple "mini-spa" apps, and the mini-spa apps all share a certain amount of code.

I am not referring to the case of trying to have multiple `ng-app` declarations on the same page; rather, I mean different sections of a large site that have their own, unique `ng-app` declaration.

As Scott Allen writes in his [OdeToCode](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2013/05/07/angularjs-abstractions-organizing-modules.aspx) blog:

> One scenario I haven't found addressed very well is the scenario where
>   multiple apps exist in the same greater web application and require
>   some shared code on the client.

Are there any recommended approaches to take, pitfalls to avoid, or good sample structures of this scenario that you can point to?

---

**Update - 9/10/2015**
One project with an interesting organization strategy is MEAN.JS and its modules folder.
https://github.com/meanjs/mean
https://github.com/meanjs/mean/tree/master/modules

Another example is from the ASP.NET Music Store SPA example. 
https://github.com/aspnet/MusicStore
https://github.com/aspnet/MusicStore/tree/master/src/MusicStore.Spa/ng-apps

Comment: What have you decided to go with? I'm in the same position where I want isolation of the application to be broken into a number of smaller self contained apps

Answer (score 8):

Here is the design that I work with. I found it useful on two larger projects I built and haven't hit any road blocks so far.

### Folder Structure

```
your-project/
  apps/
    global.html
    app1/
      index.html
      app1.module.js
      app1.js
      parts/
        foo.js
        foo.html
        ...
    app2/
  libs
    lib1/
      lib1.module.js
      parts/
        directive1.js
        directive1.html
    lib2/
  third-party/
```

- Configure your server web framework to find `apps/app1/index.html` when a request for `/app1` comes in. Use friendly URLs  (e.g. `the-first-application/` instead of `app1/` and map them using your server technology if required.
- Your server technology must include `global.html` in `index.html` because it contains the vendor includes (see below).
- Include the assets required by the respective app in `index.html` (see below).
- Put the `ng-app` and the root `<div ui-view></div>` in the `index.html`.
- Every app and lib is a separate angular module.
- Every app gets a `<app-name>.module.js` file that contains the angular module definition and dependency list.
- Every app gets a `<app-name>.js` file that contains the modules' config and run blocks, and the routing config as part of it.
- Every app gets a `parts` folder that contains the applications' controllers, views, services and directives **in a  structure that makes sense for the specific app**. I don't consider sub-folders like `controllers/`, `views/` etc helpful, because they don't scale, but YMMV.
- Libs follow the same structure as apps, but leave things out that they don't need (obviously).

Start out with services and directives within the app where they are used. As soon as you need something in another app as well, refactor to a library. Try to create functionally consistent libraries, not just all-directive or all-services libraries.

### Assets

I minify both JS and CSS files for release builds but work with unminified files during development. Here's a setup that support this:

- Manage vendor includes globally in `global.html`. This way, the heavy stuff can be loaded from cache when navigating between SPAs. Make sure caching works appropriately.
- Per-SPA assets are defined in `index.html`. This should only include the app-specific files as well as the used libraries.

The folder structure above makes it easy to find the right files for the minification build steps.

Answer (score 7):

Single Page Apps (SPAs) aren't really intended to be used the way that you're suggesting with a really large application and multiple mini-SPAs within the main one.  The biggest problem will be page load times as everything has to be loaded up front.

One way to tackle this is using a navigation page that will take you to individual SPAs.  The navigation page will be fairly lightweight, and then you'll only load one SPA at a time based upon what was selected.  You can provide a link bar with navigation links within each of your SPAs so users don't always have to go back to the navigation page when they need to go to another area.

Using this approach can create some challenges with persisting information across SPAs.  But we're talking about something SPAs weren't intended to do.  There are some frameworks that can help with client side data persistence.  Breeze is the first that comes to mind, but there are others.

---

Regarding layout - several Programmers questions address large project layout, depending upon your particular needs.  I came across [this one](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/81899/53019) and [this one](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/160326/53019).  There is nothing magical about SPAs that would affect your application layout beyond what is already answered in those questions.

That said, there are differing approaches that work best for different projects.  I would recommend sticking with the base layout as provided by the angular seed project.  Create separate folders from the provided ones for your custom packages and source code.  And within your source folder, use a project layout that makes sense for your needs.

Answer (score -1):

If your application needs multiple ng-app declarations on the same page, then you need to manually bootstrap AngularJS module, by injecting a module name as shown below :

```
angular.element(document).ready(function() {
  angular.bootstrap(document, ['TodoApp']);
});
```

This  [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/AC0iJBQEJcRTd1LLfsn3?p=preview) elaborates on how we could manually bootstrap AngularJS.

Comment: mg1075 was pretty clear that this is not the case: "I am not referring to the case of trying to have multiple ng-app declarations on the same page; rather, I mean different sections of a large site that have their own, unique ng-app declaration."